# Cannot add methods to a collection with fluent interface

Tags: c#, collections

Now I'm really stuck, after two days of googling and trying everything.
I have a JSON file with an array of records. The records are all the same, each one holds seven properties (I did craft the JSON myself, so I have full control on it). What I want to do is to inherit from a collection type to add some bells and whistles to the data received from JSON. For example, each record (it's a Braille translation table description — don't bother yourselves if you don't know what I'm talking about), has a `Language` field, so I would like to do something like that:

```
var germanTables = new TableCollection()
    .PopulateFromJson()
    .FindByLanguage("de");
```

Here's what I have currently.

#### The Record

```
public readonly record struct TranslationTable(
    string FileName,
    string DisplayName,
    string Language,
    string TableType,
    string ContractionType,
    string Direction,
    int DotsMode
)
{
    // Some helper methods
}
```

#### The Collection Class

```
public class TableCollection: ICollection<TranslationTable>
{
    private const string TablesJson = @"LibLouis\tables.json";
    private List<TranslationTable> tables = new List<TranslationTable>();

    public int Count { get; }
    public bool IsReadOnly { get; }

    public TableCollection PopulateFromJson() 
    {
        using var file = File.OpenRead(TablesJson);
        this.tables = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<TranslationTable>>(file);
        return this;
    }

    public TableCollection FindByLanguage(string Language)
    {
        // NOTE! At this stage this.tables.Count returns 1, it finds a German table
        this.tables = this.tables.FindAll((TranslationTable table) => table.Language == Language).ToList();
        return this;
    }

    public void Add(TranslationTable item) => ((ICollection<TranslationTable>)tables).Add(item);
    public void Clear() => ((ICollection<TranslationTable>)tables).Clear();
    public bool Contains(TranslationTable item) => ((ICollection<TranslationTable>)tables).Contains(item);
    public void CopyTo(TranslationTable[] array, int arrayIndex) => ((ICollection<TranslationTable>)tables).CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    public bool Remove(TranslationTable item) => ((ICollection<TranslationTable>)tables).Remove(item);
    public IEnumerator<TranslationTable> GetEnumerator() => ((IEnumerable<TranslationTable>)tables).GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => ((IEnumerable)tables).GetEnumerator();
}
```

so it does find the table where I commented (after the `FindAll()` call), but when I invoke it in the code, it returns 0:

```
var tables = new TableCollection().PopulateFromJson().FindByLanguage("de");
// It's a Serilog-powered logger, it writes to file
Log.Debug(tables.Count.ToString());
```

Disclaimer: I spent so much time on it that I might be super stupid and miss something mega obvious, please bear with me. Another thing: if my solution is suboptimal or naïve at all, I'm all ears if you suggest something else.

Comment: You never set your `Count` property that I can see...  Did you mean for it to pass through to  `this.tables.Count`?

Comment: It looks like a neat idea. But I'd be tempted to take more of a "builder" pattern approach, where you wouldn't worry about inheriting `ICollection` in the `TableCollection` at all. Then have a method like `ICollection<TranslationTable> Build() => tables` which would just return the existing `tables` list object. I can post an answer if you'd like to see that.

Alternatively, if you really want your own custom implementation of `ICollection`, then these docs might help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icollection-1?view=net-8.0#examples

Comment: Please post the answer about the Builder pattern, I wouldn't inhereit from ICollection if there is another possibility, actually. Thanks!